# BeautifulSoup: Pegar text dentro de tabela

Tags: html, python, table, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Estou tentando pegar valores específicos dentro de uma tabela, eu tenho um código similar que já utilizo da mesma forma em outra estrutura de tabela única dentro do html, o problema e que não consigo pegar o texto do campo, dentro dessa estrutura com uma tabela dentro da outra.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo a estrutura da tabela e o valor que quero pegar e o que venho tentando fazer:

```
<table id="principal">
   <tr>
       <td id="TB01">
           <table class="secondary"></table>
       </td>
       <td id="TB02">
           <table class="secondary"></table>
       </td>
       <td id="TB03">
           <table class="secondary">
               <tr></tr>
               <tr>
                   <td></td>
                   <td></td>
                   <td>ESSE VALOR -> R$5.388,50</td>
               </tr>
           </table>
       </td>
       <td id="TB04">
           <table class="secondary"></table>
       </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Código que venho tentando utilizar:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.bmf.com.br/bmfbovespa/pages/lumis/lum-boletim-online-new-ptBR.asp?Acao=BUSCA&cboMercadoria=DOL"
resp = requests.get(url)

        bs = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")

        trs = (
            bs.find("td", {"id": "TB03"})
            .find("table", {"class": "secondary"})
            .findAll("tr")
        )

        for tr in trs:
            if trs.index(tr) == 2:
                tds = tr.findAll("td")

                for td in tds:
                    if tds.index(td) == 3:
                        valor = td.get_text()
        
        print(valor)
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar em como consigo retornar o valor específico, sempre retorna None quando dou print, ou esse erro AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'.

Comment: Se alguma das respostas solucionou o seu problema, marque-a como correta. Se não, comente pedindo mais esclarecimentos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kleyton, isso acontece por que a requisição não retorna o HTML completo logo de cara. Vamos seguir com o que você fez no código:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.bmf.com.br/bmfbovespa/pages/lumis/lum-boletim-online-new-ptBR.asp?Acao=BUSCA&cboMercadoria=DOL"
resp = requests.get(url)

bs = BeautifulSoup(resp.text, "html.parser")
```

Até aqui, tá tudo certo. Temos o HTML salvo em bs. O próximo passo então é navegarmos pelo HTML atrás do elemento que queremos. Pra ficar mais claro, vou fazer isso de um jeito um pouco diferente do que você adotou, mas em essência estamos fazendo a mesma coisa, ok?

```
trs = bs.body.div.div.div.form.div.div.table.tbody.tr.find('td', id='TB03')
```

Acima, eu peguei o `HTML` bruto, selecionei o primeiro `body`, dentro dele a primeira `div`, dentro dela a primeira `div`, e assim por diante, até chegar na tag `<tr />`, onde queremos especificamente a que tem `id=TB03`.

Neste momento, se você der um `print(trs)` vai perceber que ele retorna:

```
>>> <td id="TB03"></td>
```

Repare que a tag está vazia. É a partir daqui que tudo desanda. O trecho marcado com `>>> <<<`:

```
    trs = (
        bs.find("td", {"id": "TB03"})
        >>>.find("table", {"class": "secondary"})<<<
        .findAll("tr")
    )
```

vai retornar `None`, pois não há nada lá dentro, e a linha seguinte vai retornar erro, pois como a própria mensagem `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'.` já diz, não é possível usar o método `find()` de `None`, pois ele não possui tal método, não possui nada, aliás.

> **Porquê isso acontece?**

Se você for na página que está tentando raspar, com o console do navegador aberto na aba de mmonitoramento de rede vai ver isso:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que acontece é que, nas primeiras requisições `GET`, é baixado um HTML de template, depois outras requisições solicitam dados ao servidor para preencher os espaços vazios com as informações que o usuário deseja ver. Ou seja, o HTML que você está obtendo no seu código ainda não possui os dados que você deseja raspar

> **Como proceder então?**

Ainda observando a imagem acima, você pode ver que uma requisição `GET` é feita ao endereço `http://cotacao.b3.com.br/mds/api/v1/DerivativeQuotation/DOL`, que retorna um `JSON` gigante. Acredito que essas são as informações que você procura. Para obtê-las via python basta fazer:

```
url = "http://cotacao.b3.com.br/mds/api/v1/DerivativeQuotation/DOL"
resp = requests.get(url)
```

e o `JSON` estará acessível através de `resp.content`. Agora é só tratar os dados da maneira que você precisar que eles fiquem, isso é com você

Comment: Obrigado yoyo, funcionou perfeitamente, já tinha duvidado que o problema seria no delay do carregamento da página, mas não tinha pensado dessa forma sua explicação me ajudou bastante, já consegui extrair os dados diretamente do JSON, obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Conforme dito na outra resposta é carregado um 'template' para ser alimentado, dessa forma o requests não consegue pegar os valores corretos.

Utilizando requests_html

Importando a lib

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession
```

Criando a sessão

```
session = HTMLSession()
```

Fazendo a requisição

```
r = session.get('http://www.bmf.com.br/bmfbovespa/pages/lumis/lum-boletim-online-new-ptBR.asp?Acao=BUSCA&cboMercadoria=DOL')
```

Renderizando para trabalho com o javascript da página(neste momento é feito um download de um arquivo requerido pela lib, este será realizado apenas uma vez)

```
r.html.render()
```

Pegando o elemento na página

```
tb03 = r.html.find('#TB03',first=True)
```

Imprimindo

```
print(tb03.text)
```

Comment: Amigo obrigado pela ajuda, venho tentando fazer dessa forma mas não está funcionando, tentei como você comentou que não é muito diferente do que venho tentando fazer mas continua retornando o mesmo erro ou  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'findAll'.

Comment: Me passa o site para eu verificar direto da fonte

Comment: Eu me confundi na hora de escrever o código e troquei o class por id no html lá em cima mas percebi e alterei no código que você me deu de exemplo, ok vou atualizar o URL direto no meu código!

Comment: @kleytonsolinho Atualizei a resposta, abraço!